# HTTP ERROR 503 - Ubuntu 18.04 -- AllowOverride All

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, virtualhost

Recibo un error 503 en la web siempre que cambia **AllowOverride None** a **AlowOverride All**

Lo hago para que pueda leer el .htaccess
Actualmente uso Ubuntu 18.04, pero, antes también me salía en CentOS 7.

Cuando lo vuelvo a poner con None y ejecuto, **systemctl restart apache2**, todo vuelve a estar bien, pero el .htaccess no funciona.

Comment: Para este tipo de preguntas, siempre será valioso poner el contenido (el relacionado) de los logs de acceso y de errores en Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución:**

1. Encender el módulo Apache mod_rewrite

   a2enmod rewrite
2. Cambiar de None a All (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

   AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco cuál es exactamente tu problema porque no entregas suficiente información, pero si tuviese que adivinar, diría que es probablemente alguna directiva del **.htaccess**, porque **AllowOverride All** significa que cualquier opción global que hayas declarado en tu virtualhost puede ser sobreescrita por tu **.htaccess**.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Claudio.

Así es, es para que pueda leer el .htaccess, pero, siempre que coloco AllowOverride All sale el error 503.

Comment: Claro, cada vez que colocas "AllowOverride All", porque esa directiva permite que el .htaccess incorpore o sustituya configuraciones globales, como por ejemplo: FollowSymLinks, Indexes o alguna directiva Rewrite (RewriteRule, RewriteBase, etc.). Lo que desconozco, porque no lo comentas, es si antes del cambio funcionaba o no

Comment: Mi error fue que no ejecuté "a2enmod rewrite".